# Retrieving objects from DataSnapshot Firebase in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a small shift management application where shifts are stored in Firebase's database.
I would like to fetch all shifts related to a date (every date has different number of shifts).

For this purpose I created the following database :

```js
  // previous dates 
     "20190415" : [ null, {
    "end" : "16:00",
    "name" : "morningShift",
    "numOfEmps" : 3,
    "start" : "08:00",
    "wage" : 0
  }, {
    "emps" :  null,
    "end" : "00:00",
    "name" : "eveningShift",
    "numOfEmps" : 3,
    "start" : "16:00",
  }, {
    "emps" :  null,
    "end" : "08:00",
    "name" : "nightShift",
    "numOfEmps" : 3,
    "start" : "00:00",
  } ],
  // following dates
```

My code in Java is as follows:

```
    // Retrieve shifts per date from Firebase
// Date passed to this function is of form - YYYYMMDD
public static void fetchShiftsPerDayFromDB(String date, final Callback callback)
{
    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("config").child("shiftsPerDay").child(date);
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            ArrayList<Shift> shifts = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot shiftSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                // Retrieve Shift from Database
                Shift shift = new Shift();
                shift.setName(shiftSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
                shift.setStart(shiftSnapshot.child("start").getValue().toString());
                shift.setEnd(shiftSnapshot.child("end").getValue().toString());
                shift.setNumOfEmps((int)shiftSnapshot.child("numOfEmps").getValue());
                shift.setWage((int)shiftSnapshot.child("wage").getValue());
            //    shift.setEmpsList(null);

                shifts.add(shift);
            }
           callback.shiftsCallback(shifts);
        }
```

But the for loop would not execute. What could be the issue here?

I'd appreciate help.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe double check your firebase structure ?

Comment: The structure seems to be correct. When I debug , the key is correctly recognized as "20190415" but the value is null.